# The formatting of the string appears to be incorrect, as 1 should be a value, and not a number

Tags: php

the title is a response i got working with hostgator about a php file I'm using to connect with my web mysql.  Here's the suggestion from Hostgator:

> "The error here is in the formatting of the string, There's a similar string higher in the file, that functions properly:

```
$query = sprintf("insert into `tinywebdb` (`tag`, `value`) values ('%s', '%s')",
```

This one shows values ('%s', '%s') and functions properly.

THE STRING WITH THE ERROR IS:

```
$query = sprintf("select `tag`, `value` from `tinywebdb` where `tag` = '%s' limit 1", mysql_real_escape_string($tag));
```

In short, the formatting of the string appears to be incorrect, as 1 should be a value, and not a number.

I need help fixing the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_real_escape_string() is deprecated. You should read the [mysql_real_escape_string doc](https://www.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for info on how to replace it.